# Visual Studio c++ how do I find the containing namespace for a given class/method

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I come from C# development in Visual Studio, and when I type a class name, or object name from a namespace I have not yet imported (used?), I can simply type `ctr+.` and then Visual Studio will show a drop down list of possible namespaces I can import.

However, this is not working in C++. Does VS have this feature for c++ development? `ctr+.` does not work.

I spent 45 minutes last night trying to draw a Rectangle on Windows Universal App, because Rectangle's namespace was not included, and `ctr+.` was not showing me any options - I did not even know if `Rectangle` existed in c++ Universal Apps. Eventually after searching MSDN website forever I finally found a Rectangle page which showed its namespace. It would be a pain to search through tons of documentation every time I want to use an class or method just to find its namespace (especially if I am unsure if the class even exists).

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Object Browser window (View > Object Browser). Enter the type-name into the Search box and all of the matches will (eventually) be displayed in the left-hand pane. Click a result to see its type information, though it won't include the name of the assembly/winmd file.

Note that the Object Browser is old and slow - fundamentally unchanged since Visual Studio 2002 (it even blocks the UI thread when it searches!). I find using the local Help Viewer is faster (<kbd>F1</kbd> > Search > select topic) and it tells me what assembly/winmd file I need to reference too, though as it's the help viewer it won't automatically add those references in VS for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful. Though not what VS does for C#, I can at least search through all possible options, and it also shows the namespace! Thank you. I will vote as correct answer when the timer runs out.